# Cannot install app from Play store - fail to connect

Tags: google-play-store, installation, application-error

Installing an application from the Play store fails to download, a brief message states

> "please open my apps to establish a connection with the server"

Search and update work as expected. Only downloading fails.

*This issue pertains to any application on both Wifi and cellular networks. Restarting the phone or connection (e.g. Toggling flight mode) fail to resolve this particular occurrence of the issue (but worth trying first!). Also if it was a generic connection issue search and update would likely be impacted. Hope this helps someone in the future.*

Comment: Sorry but this question can not be answered, as it misses all relevant information (what app, what connection, ...). Please update the question or delete it.

Comment: @Robert those are not omissions, the issue was clearly the play store app. So every application and every connection. I could of course make this point clearer. It is brief but my Google foo found no good Q&A so it wanted something future people could find

Answer (score 1):

Clear play store data, and try again. On samsung device, S7 specifically go to:

Settings > Apps Manager > Google Play Store > Storage

*Clear data*

(Clear Cache is also an option but does not seem sufficient to resolve this error)